# Can't add row to jQuery data table

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatables

I am trying to add rows to a jQuery data table once the submit button on a modal pop up is clicked. I convert the data from pop up to a JSON string and pass it to a function to populate the data table but keep getting datatable warning about "requested unknown parameter 'Name'". I checked to make sure number of columns and data points are the same, since this seems to be the usual cause of this error.

This is what I have tried:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnNewEduSubmit", function (event) {debugger
    var isValid = validateEducationSubmit();

    if (isValid) {
        var name = $('#tbName').val();
        var location = $('#tbLocation').val();
        var degree = $('#ddlDegree').find("option:selected").text();
        var degreeID = $('#ddlDegree').val();
        var field = $('#tbField').val();
        var startDate = $('#tbEduStartDate').val();
        var enddate = $('#tbEduEndDate').val();
        var notes = $('#taNotes').val();

        var params = JSON.stringify("{ 'Name': '" + name + "', 'Location': '" + location + "', 'Degree': '" + degree + "', 'DegreeID':'" + degreeID + "', 'Field': '" + field + "', 'StartDate': '" + startDate + "', 'EndDate': '" + enddate + "', 'Notes': '" + notes + "' }");
        populateTable(params, tblEdu);
    }
});

function populateTable(parameters, table) {debugger
    var jResult = JSON.parse(parameters);
    table.row.add(jResult).draw(); <--- Error here, i can see 'Name' parameter
    table.columns([8]).visible(false);
    table.draw(false);
}

var tblEdu = $("#EducationTable").DataTable({
    jQueryUI: true,
    data: [],
    dom: 't',
    order: [[4, "asc"]],
    autoWidth: false,
    "oLanguage": {
        "sEmptyTable": "No Education Info Was Found."
    },
    "columns": [
        {
            "data": "Name"
        }, {
            "data": "Location"
        }, {
            "data": "Degree"
        }, {
            "data": "Field"
        }, {
            "data": "StartDate"
        }, {
            "data": "EndDate"
        }, {
            "data": "Notes"
        }, {
            "render": function (data, type, row) {
                // This doesn't work either when I click on "delete" link!
                var cellContent =
                    "<a href='javascript:' onclick=\"tblEdu.row().remove().draw(false) \">Delete</a>";
                return cellContent;
            }
        }, {
            "data": "DegreeID"
        }
    ],
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "targets": [8],
            "visible": "false",
            "searchable": "false"
        }
    ]
});
```

After the error pop up is closed, a row of nulls is added to data table.

Comment: share your html code

Comment: Check with static json data. It would be good, if you share html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the error is in your json stringfy and then the decode. if you are converting javascript objects to json, then it should be like `{ name: "John", age: 30, city: "New York" }` -> no ' ' on the keys. If you are using this "{ 'Name': '" + name + "', ... }", it is already a json string, you can send it directly to the DataTable.

Comment: Thanks. had to change parameter to: var params = JSON.stringify({ Name: name, Location: location, ...;

Comment: nice! glad to help